# Deploying Aurelia to a server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I have learnt the basics of Aurelia using the aurelia-cli and now i want to deploy a simple app. I am basically using Aurelia in place of Angular in a MEAN stack. The documentation is very unhelpful to a newbie in this regard and all the posts and tuts on this topic seems to be before the CLI was fully implemented. There are many tuts on building a mean app, and very few on deploying.

The question is this: How does one go about delpoying a ME(A)N application?

Comment: Get node hosting, upload your code, set start command to start your server, and there you go, app deployed.

Comment: I don't know about MEAN apps but you'll want to start with `au build --env prod` to create your final bundles, and then upload your index.html and scripts folder to your webserver.

Comment: @LStarky thanks for the advice! I tried this however the vendor-bundle.js kept returning a 404 error. Do you know why this might happen?

Comment: 404 means Not Found, which would lead me to believe that the vendor-bundle.js file was not in the expected location when you uploaded it to your server.